# Why does the Temperature Decrease?

Tags: thermodynamics, temperature

[image]

This is from a calorimetry lab. $50\ \mathrm{ml}$ of acid and base were mixed. Why does the temperature keep decreasing after 1 minute and why isn't at a constant rate?

Is it because heat is lost to the surroundings?

---

Source: https://fronter.com/uio/links/files.phtml/1520337012$477794732$/Lab/Laboppgaver+-++Prelab++-+Rapportmal/Oppgave+2+all.pdf

This for a Lab Report Hand-IN at my University. Blindern University of Oslo.

Comment: Heat loss to surroundings is probably it.

Comment: The link is not visible to the general public. This is unlikely due to heat loss, as that wouldn't be linear. Especially not if it wasn't well-mixed, which it probably isn't. More information is going to be needed.